# Get page id by title?

Tags: pages, id

I'm using the following code to insert the content from another wp page into my main home page.

Is it possible to make it work with a page **title** instead of an id number?

Eg. Not $page_id = 518 but $page_id = 'about'  instead????

```
$page_id = 518; //Your Page ID
$page_data = get_page( $page_id );
// Displays the title
echo '<h1>'. $page_data->post_title .'</h1>';
// Displays the content
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function exactly for that:

```
get_page_by_title( $page_title, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'page' );
```

You can use it like this:

```
$page = get_page_by_title( 'Start' );
```

To get the page from a specific post type:

```
$custom = get_page_by_title( 'Start', OBJECT, 'your_custom_post_type' );
$post   = get_page_by_title( 'Start', OBJECT, 'post' );
```

Be aware, this function will search in *all* post statuses. So you might get a draft, a trashed or private post. You should check the result with:

```
$status = get_post_status( $page );

if ( 'publish' !== $status )
    return; // do not show unpublished posts
```

A related function is `get_page_by_path()`:

```
$page = get_page_by_path( 'about/contact' );
```

Comment: It's now 2024, 11 years later, `get_page_by_title()` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Function `get_page_by_title()` is deprecated. Use `WP_Query` instead or try something like this:

```
/**
     * Retrieves a link to a page object based on page title  
     * @param $title string Page title
     * @return $link Page object permalink
     */
    function get_page_object( $title ) {
       $array_of_objects = get_posts([
            'title' => $title,
            'post_type' => 'page',
        ]);
        $id = $array_of_objects[0]; 
        $id = $id->ID;
        $link = get_permalink($id); 
        return $link;
    }
```